# Button Click element issue in selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to click button(name command page) on web page but i am unable to do so. i am using selenium with python

code:

```
wait= WebDriverWait(driver,20)
command_page = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"Button_ID")))
command_page.click()
```

I have tried by class name also but i am unable to click the element.
Please help me on this.

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: I am not getting any exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative you can use JavascriptExecutor to perfrom click on certain element if Selenium `click()` method doesn't trigger the action without any Exception.

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("etoolbar_toolbarSection_newcommandpagebtn_id")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: @PRAYANK, Glad to hear!!! Please accept the answer by click on tick mark below the vote count on answer. So it can be helpful for others. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try below solution :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
both_button=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Command Page')]")))
both_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, seems to be working

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("file://c:/cygwin64/home/das2/abcd.html")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("etoolbar_toolbarSection_newcommandpagebtn_id")
element.click()
```